# Change the field class on error

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-widget

I want to change the input field class and other attributes in case of error.

So in form **init** :

```
 for f_name in self.fields:
            if f_name in self.errors:
                self.fields[f_name].widget.attrs['error'] = a
            else:
                self.fields[f_name].widget.attrs['error'] = b
```

Now, I want to cycle thru the widget attributes and remove some attributes, not to be added to the html field(see error in this case).

```
{% for name, value in widget.attrs.items %}{% if name is not error %}{% if value is not False %} .....
```

the condition is not working:

```
{% if name is not error %}
```

I tried  `is not, !=` , `is not in(error, alpha)` also using error as string 'error'

are not working, but

```
{% if name == error %} is working
```

I don't understand why, because it should work as in normal python.

The value of error can variate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

```
{% if name != 'error' %}
```

You are missing '', it's trying to compare it to another variable.

Comment: I tried as string also, what about in one of the variables, not in ('a','b') gives me an error